# How to avoid whitespace being replaced by %20 in URL?

Tags: php, url, whitespace

If have URL like `www.test.com/all properties` , its fine in Firefox but in all other browser the whitespace is being replaced by %20 by default and the URL look like this  `www.test.com/all%20properties`. I want url like  `www.test.com/all properties`. How to handle this?

Comment: I suggest you avoid using spaces, and maybe replace them by a '-'. Anyway URL presentation is the browser behavior, you have absolutely no control on it, and %20 is the correct standard representation.

Comment: @Parallelis: Thanks for your reply. purposefully i need like this URL `www.test.com/all properties`, the value `all properties` is coming from DB